# Prime Factor in Power form

Tags: java

The following program gives the output :
3^3*5^1*
but I need : 3^3*5^1
How to avoid the last '*' ?

public class PmFact {

```
      public static void numFreq(List<Integer> l) {

        Map<Integer, Integer> hm = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>(); 

        for (Integer i : l) { 
            Integer j = hm.get(i); 
            hm.put(i, (j == null) ? 1 : j + 1); 
        } 


        for (Map.Entry<Integer, Integer> val : hm.entrySet()) { 
            System.out.print(val.getKey() + "^" + val.getValue() + "*");    
        } 

    } 

public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<Integer> l = new ArrayList<>();
    l.add(3);
    l.add(3);
    l.add(3);
    l.add(5);
    numFreq(l);

}
```

}

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you're using Java 8+, `stream()` the entry set and map each value as `x^y` and then collect with [`Collectors.joining(CharSequence)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#joining-java.lang.CharSequence-). Like,

```
System.out.println(hm.entrySet().stream().map(val -> String.format("%s^%s", 
        val.getKey(), val.getValue())).collect(Collectors.joining("*")));
```

Also, since Java 7, you can use the diamond operator `<>`. Change,

```
Map<Integer, Integer> hm = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();
```

to

```
Map<Integer, Integer> hm = new HashMap<>();
```

Outputs (as expected)

```
3^3*5^1
```

You could replace the *middle bit* as well, and I would suggest using more meaningful names (`hm` isn't so bad, but `l` looks a lot like `1`). Putting that all together might look something like

```
public static void numFreq(List<Integer> list) {
    Map<Integer, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();
    list.stream().forEach(i -> map.put(i, 1 + map.getOrDefault(i, 0)));

    System.out.println(map.entrySet().stream().map(val -> String.format("%s^%s",
             val.getKey(), val.getValue())).collect(Collectors.joining("*")));
}
```

Comment: *Suggestion:* If you're going to give a Stream answer for the printing part, you should also show how to do the group/count logic with Stream, even though that's not been asked, for completeness. --- Or just ignore my OCD 

Comment: @Andreas Good advice. Added.

Comment: Or maybe: `list.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity(), Collectors.counting()))`